# Encrypt/Hide Createdby Field

Tags: custom-object

Is there a way to encrypt, hide, or make the created by field on a custom object anonymous? We are creating a survey process and we want the record submitters/creators to remain anonymous. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from hiding the field on the page layout there's not a lot you could do. One solution might be to use a batch job, Visualforce page (or a manual approach) where one person creates all of the records (initially empty) that others then fill in. You'd still have to deal with the last modified by/date though.

Comment: Thanks this is more what I am looking for. This would be for internal users so I don't want to go the whole route of creating a site, more just restricting access. I'll have to play around with this last modified more.

Answer (score 2):

If "security by obscurity" is good enough (i.e. you only share the URL with the users you want to survey), you could create an unauthenticated Force.com site to contain the survey pages. Then all the records would be owned by the "site guest user".

Comment: Great idea. You might want to combine this with sending out one off access codes or something (you could do that via URL parameters) just to add some level of security to it.

Comment: @LaceySnr Good thought. And perhaps something that is single use only.